# Find files that have been changed recursively

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a simple script to recursively rip through a directory and check if any of the files have been changed. I only have the traversal so far:

```
import fnmatch
import os 
from optparse import OptionParser

rootPath = os.getcwd() 
pattern = '*.js' 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):    
    for filename in files:        
        print( os.path.join(root, filename))
```

I have two issues:

**1. How do I tell if a file has been modified?**

**2. How can I check if a directory has been modified?** - I need to do this because the folder I wish to traverse is *huge*. If I can check if the dir has been modified and not recursively rip through an unchanged dir, this would *greatly* help.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to clarify a little on what you mean by modified. Are you comparing against a snapshot? Or just looking for modifications within an interval of time?

Comment: You can not know if anything has changed without a frame of reference. Modified since a time? Modified from a snapshot? Etc...

Comment: Ah, good point. I am comparing it to another folder.

Comment: Could you use hashlib? Make md5 hashes of each file in each folder, (key=>filename, value=>md5 hash)and compare against their counterparts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comparing two files between two folders, you can use [os.path.getmtime()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) on both files and compare the results. If they're the same, they haven't been modified. Note that this will work on both files and folders.

Answer (score 1):

The typical fast way to tell if a file has been modified is to use `os.path.getmtime(path)` (assuming a Linux or similar environment).  This will give you the modification timestamp, which you can compare to a stored timestamp to determine if a file has been modified.

`getmtime()` works on directories too, but it will only tell you whether a file has been added, removed or renamed in the directory; it will not tell you whether a file has been modified inside the directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own implementation of what you might be looking for. Mind that, beside timestamps you might want to track files that have been added or deleted too (like i do). If not you can just change the code on line:

```
if now == before:
```

here is the code:

```
# check if any txt file in folder "wd" has been modified (rewritten added or deleted)
def src_dir_modified(wd):
    now = []
    global before
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(wd,'*.txt'))

    for infile in all_files:
        now.append([infile, os.stat(infile).st_mtime])
    if now == before: # compare files and their time stamps
        return False
    else:
        before = now
        print 'Source code has been modified.'
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can admit the use of a command-line tool, you could use `rsync` instead of re-inventing the wheel. `rsync` uses file modification time and file size to decide if a file has been changed or not.

`rsync --verbose --recursive --dry-run dir1 dir2` should get the differences between files in `dir1` and `dir2`. You can write the output to a log file to act on it.